# Htaccess redirection (www.example.com/page.html/page.html) not redirecting to 404 page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Currently, when we open a page `www.example.com/page.html/page.html` it's not redirecting to 404 pages instead it's opening a page without CSS. I want this to be redirected to 404 pages else it should open the `page.html` properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> www.example.com/page.html/page.html
> ```

Assuming `/page.html` is a valid file then the additional `/page.html` on the end is *additional pathname information* (path-info). You need to disable path-info in your `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

Now, any URL that contains *path-info* will trigger a 404 instead. (Unless you have other directives that route the request.)

Ordinarily, path-info it is disabled by default on `.html` files, unless this has been explicitly enabled or the handler is changed (eg. passing `.html` files through PHP).

Comment: Thanks for your answers its redirecting to 404 pages but it not taking the CSS and js file the original path (www.example.com/page.html/page.html)

Comment: "but it not taking the CSS and js file the original path" - not sure exactly what you mean? Are you saying that the CSS and JS are not being rendered in your custom 404 error document?

Comment: when is use(www.example.com/wqeqweqew.html) it's opening 404 page properly without any CSS and JS issue?  when I try to open (www.example.com/page.html/page.html) CSS and JS missing

Comment: That will happen if you are using _relative_ URLs to your static resources. You need to use root-relative (or absolute) URLs instead in your error document. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmatsers stack for more detail: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Comment: thanks, MrWhite. you made my day. Its been resolved